# Razor Page create class instance and share to whole session

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am creating a simple Web App that takes a unique key as login and uses that key to pull data from various api endpoints. I have the key input and data pull working correctly, the issue is that I create an instance of the data (to allow for multiple users at once, static data won't work right?) and I cannot access that user instance variable from the rest of the app.

I have been trying to serialize the class instance to a json string and add that to temp data like so:

```
'''
user = new User();
TempData["user"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);

return RedirectToPage("NextPage");
'''
```

This seems to work correctly when I set a breakpoint and inspect TempData at the return line. So, then I try to access the json string to deserialize in the NextPage view like so:

```
'''
@page
@using Newtonsoft.Json
@model NextPageModel

@{

    User user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>((string)TempData["user"]);
}
'''
```

The NextPage loads correctly when I'm not trying to pass data, but when I'm trying it this way I get a "ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_TOO_BIG" which makes sense given the json string is HUGE. Can someone please help me figure this out?

Comment: each page should load its own data... not pass it around.  also if this data is static and shared.... why not make it static and shared?

Comment: I may be thinking about it wrong, if it's static is the variable shared between users? the issue would be that each user has a different key that they input for the api endpoint, would it not load the same data for each person?

Comment: it's unclear on your purpose of sharing the data. When sharing a data, you need to clearly define the scope that data is shared. Here the scope can be in a request processing time or by expire time or by some other dynamic condition. So basically it's like caching. And caching can b exposed via `IMemoryCache` or `IDistributedCache` (some kind of caching service). You can inject that service everywhere you need.

Comment: Note that `TempData` is readable until it's read (so basically it means it's read ***once*** and gone). So be sure that it's what you need. Of course it has methods to peek the data multiple times (instead of reading once and deleting). It's backed by cookies by default (hence the limit in size when sent via the header `Cookie`) but you can switch to back it by session state (kind of in-memory store) using `services.AddMvc().AddSessionStateTempDataProvider()`. I would avoid session state if possible.

Comment: Sorry I think I was unclear - I want to ensure that data is NOT shared. I'm trying to do this without authentication or need of a database. For example, I have my API key that I put into the form, hit submit, and then the api requests go through and it displays my data. Now, IF these are static variables for the data and someone else enters their api key to get their data, would it change the api key for my session?

... I might need a nap.